# How to allow the user to select data from firestore through specifying the document name?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a little app where the user can find values of documents.

As a database I am using Firestore Database. I only have one collection "storage" with many documents and 3 value fields per document. I already built an activity that gets the 3 value fields from the database (see below).

What I am trying to do now is to let the user decide which values he wants to see by selecting different database document names.

For example if the user types in "apple" in the text input field, I want to show him the 3 values that I have saved in the **collection "storage" -> document "apple" -> fields "value1", "value2" and "value3"**. If the user types in "banana" in the text input field, I want to show him the 3 values that I have saved in the **collection "storage" -> document "banana" -> fields "value1", "value2" and "value3"**.

Could anyone give me a few tips how to implement that? Unfortunately I couldnt find much help elsewhere.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.test

import  android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val db = Firebase.firestore

    val value1= findViewById(R.id.value1) as TextView
    val value2= findViewById(R.id.value2) as TextView
    val value3= findViewById(R.id.value3) as TextView


    db.collection("storage")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                Log.d("exist", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")

                value1.text = document.getString("value1")
                value2.text = document.getString("value2")
                value3.text = document.getString("value3")

            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w("notexisting", "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }


}
}
```

**activity_main.xml** (looks horrible, but for now I just wanna work out the functionality)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.585" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.873"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.585" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.162"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="383dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your search here..." />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error message for new error:

[image]

Error in the code:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- storage (collection)
       |
       --- apple (document)
       |    |
       |    --- value1: "v1"
       |    |
       |    --- value2: "v2"
       |    |
       |    --- value3: "v3"
       |
       --- banana (document)
            |
            --- value1: "v1"
            |
            --- value2: "v2"
            |
            --- value3: "v3"
```

To get the values of the three properties, for example, for the "apple" document, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val storageRef = rootRef.collection("storage")
storageRef.document("apple").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
    if (document != null) {
        val v1 = document.getString("value1")
        value1.text = v1
        val v2 = document.getString("value2")
        value2.text = v2
        val v3 = document.getString("value3")
        value3.text = v3
        Log.d(TAG, v1 + "/" + v2 + "/" + v3)
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
}
```

So you have to specify the name of the collection as well the name of the document when building the reference. The output in your logcat will be:

```
v1/v2/v3
```

Comment: Thanks you Alex! It works with the different documents and I can see the numbers in the logcat but I cannot see the numbers anymore when I run the app. Do I have to change anything in the activity_main.xml file as well?

Comment: Would you also know a way to let the user specify which document should be selected? That would be very helpful

Comment: Please try the changes in my updated answer, in which you can assign the values to the TextViews.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you should add my code into a method, and instead of using the hard-coded value "apple", use a variable. And call the method with what the uses searches. Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: If you have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question with everything you have tried, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will post a new question for the second topic.

Just one last problem: the ".text" is marked red for all three values and when I try to run the app I get the error "Unresolved reference: text". Do you have an idea what could cause that?

Comment: Show me a screenshot of the error. Are you sure `value1` in `value1.text` is a TextView? I just copy and paste it from your code.

Comment: Try also the simplified version from my updated answer. Does it work that way?

Comment: I added the screenshot in the question. Unfortunately the short version shows a similar error

Comment: added the picture. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please also show me how is value1 defined. For sure it's not a TextView, right?

Comment: Ofc. I added a screenshot of the old code (as in my question) and the new code I replaced it with. When I take back the 3 ".... as TextView" lines at the top, I still have the problem. The activity_main.xml file is unchanged

Comment: It's not about the activity_main.xml file. You have all of the vales1, value2, and value3 lines commented. Have you tried to uncomment them? How did you define them in your class?

Comment: Yes, if I uncomment them the problem is exactly the same. I did not define them elsewhere. I did nothing that cannot be seen in the two files